# Image slider with 5 images, Center image is bigger than others

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to develop an image slider from scratch. I am new to jquery, I've seen other examples of sliders on the internet but I can't make my way through what i want in the slider.

[image]

This is the screenshot of the layout I have made. I don't need the full code but I'd like to know the algorithm and stuff to be used.

This is what I've tried so far, Cause I can't get my way through it, I'm pretty new to jquery/javascript

```css
.slider {
        background: red;
        display: flex;
}

.slider-image {
        position: absolute;
}

.slider-image img {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        var currentImg = 3;
                        var imgHeight  = 200;
                        var imgWidth = 400;
                        var maxImgShow = 5;
                        
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                var slider-image = $(".slider-image");

                        });
                </script>
                <title>Image slider</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="slider">
                        <div class="slider-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></div>
                        <div class="slider-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></div>
                        <div class="slider-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></div>
                        <div class="slider-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></div>
                        <div class="slider-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added the code, I've not done much its kind of start I just can't get my way through it, If you could help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it autoplay or user will click to move ?

If you want auto moving, you are searching for Carousel Slideshow

[Here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/carousel.htm) is one sample

You will need to change

```
 sides:6,
```

To

```
sides:10,
```

in code in body section in above example as you need to show 5 images

Comment: That is not what I am actually looking for, I want only 5 images to be shown even if there are lots of images behind. The first layer contain the biggest image and only 1 image. Second layer contains 2 images smaller than 1st, third layer contain 2 images smaller than second layer images. Like I've shown in the Image and I want animation effect in which the current pic is focused others are kind of blurred or translucent.

Comment: And yes the user will click to move, its autoplay aswell and user can use arrow keys too